# AC Heatpump fails after cooling for few hours

Tags: air-conditioning, heat-pump, compressor, air

I live in the lower Ohio area. I have a heatpump, Airtemp brand air conditioning system that's only 6 years old, on days that are in the mid to high 80s (or hotter) the system will run until about 2:00 or 3:00 p.m. and then the compressor will shut off and the house goes up to the mid to the high 70+. Vents just blow room temp air.

I have an energy monitoring system on my panel that monitors all my circuits and I noticed when the air conditioning starts out the outside compressor runs at about 1300 Watts and few hors later it will climb up to 2,000 w when I notice the system stops working. now the fan will continue to run outside but the line going into the house is air temperature and not cold and sweaty.

If I let the system off a couple hours I can turn it back on and it will cool and usually it runs all night without any issues

Had two HVAC companies out to look at it but since it always works when they're here and it doesn't give any error codes there's not much they can do. They said the two pressures are just were it should be when they hooked up gauges.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any chance you have a smart thermostat provided/controlled by your power company?

Comment: I also have an energy monitor, and I can tell you that the wattage increasing with the heat of the day is normal.  I'm not saying the amount of power your unit is using is normal (I don't know the specs for it), but an increase is normal.  My unit uses 2400w in the morning and is up to 2900w in the heat of the afternoon.  That said, high compressor temp switches and high pressure switches are a thing, and those could be stopping your compressor if there is something wrong.

Comment: No smart thermostat

Comment: It's possible that the power company is doing load shedding that's turning off your compressor when overall, system-wide power usage exceeds their ability to supply it. I think that's the kind of "smart switch" that @crip659 was talking about.

Comment: Is the airflow rate over the evaporator coil OK when it is not cooling? So have you excluded freezing up of evap coil and blocking airflow? This would be due to low refrigerant level.

Comment: @FreeMan  The kind I was thinking are the ones a power company gives you at discounted/free and they override your control of the temperature setting when they need.  Load shedding might work also, but that should affect OP's neighbours also.

Comment: OP didn't say anything about the neighbors AC... :) Also, schedule an HVAC tech to come out in the afternoon (around the time you expect failure) on a day that's forecast to be hot enough to get you a shutdown. Don't let them schedule you "next available", make sure its when there's the highest likelihood of failure.

Comment: sounds like it's undersized, low on "freon", or clogged. Many heat pumps can't run continuously in certain extreme situations (too hot or too cold), so they shut down while the coils thaw.